# ¿Cómo leer un archivo de texto con pipes "|"?

Tags: java, archivo

Mi problema actual es como se puede leer los archivos de texto con java pero que contengan los pipes `"|"` y que en cada separación me obtenga la palabra que esta contenida en ellos.

Código Para leer actualmente:

```
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sCurrentLine.length(); i++) {
            String separado[] = sCurrentLine.split("|");
            System.out.println(separado[i]);
        }

       // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
```

Estructura de Archivo de texto que debo de leer:

```
Walther|28|M
Martha|28|F
Julio|28|M
```

El resultado actual es:

```
W
a
l
t
h
e
r
|
2
8
|
M
M
a
r
t
h
a
|
2
8
|
F
J
u
l
i
o
|
2
8
|
M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema está en que `.split()` está dentro del `for` cuando debería estar afuera

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] separado = sCurrentLine.split("|");
    for (int i = 0; i < separado.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(separado[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya realice esa modificación, pero sigue saliendo el mismo resultado. no se a que se pueda deber ese bug de lógica.

Comment: @David aseugrate que modificaste la linea del `for` interior. Ese es otro problema que se resolvio aqui, aunque no lo menciona.

Comment: @David intentaste escapando el caracter "|" ? o sea usar "\|" en vez del pipe solo?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de arriba es correcta pero con todo también, puedes usar lo siguiente usando scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String[] matches = myString.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matches[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: me dice cannot find symbol en esta linea  ´matches .length();´ al momento de hacer el for

Comment: Hay un espacio en el código, ya lo corregí.

Answer (score 0):

El metodo split espera recibir un regex, el caracter '|' es un caracter especial para regex por lo que debes escaparlo.

```
List<String> lines = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readLines(file);
for(String line : lines){
    String words[] = line.split("\\|");
}
```